# How to send date in form

Tags: html, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I send date from my form ?
In previous form I have something like this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
```

But now I have:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
```

So how I can pass my data ?

Comment: set `value='SOME THING'`

Comment: where is your **date**??

Comment: How are you generating html?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for..

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="SOME THING" placeholder="Login">
```

Answer (score 0):

add an 'id' attribute in your  tag, and on postback of your form, you can query the form elements by id. Thats what the MVC code you posted does internally.